# Identifying/dropping duplicates in 2 columns based on groupby based on multiple-columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, duplicates

Looking to first identify then drop duplicates based on identical values across rows in 2 columns. But the caveat is that I to first groupby based on other columns. Please help!

Here is a sample data:

```
   studentid   subj   topic  lesson  testtime    responsetime
1  1           math   add    a       timestamp1  45sec
2  1           math   add    a       timestamp1  45sec
2  1           math   add    a       timestamp2  30sec
2  1           math   add    a       timestamp3  15sec
2  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  0sec
2  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  0sec
2  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  45sec
2  1           math   add    b       timestamp1  45sec
```

I want to be able to first see which are the duplicates to identify any duplicate patterns in   `['testtime','responsetime']` when grouped by

```
df.groupby(['studentid','subj','topic','lesson').
```

And then be able to drop them.
I couldn't find any documentation on how to check for and then drop duplicates when using groupby method. Please help!

Comment: I should add that the actual df is larger so I do need to specify that I only want to focus on testtime and responsetime as the 2 columns I am looking and checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do

```
df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['studentid','subj','topic','lesson')
```

Comment: I tried `df_duplicates = df.drop_duplicates(['testtime','responsetime'],keep='first').groupby([''studentid','subj','topic','lesson])`.... but my question is this? Does the `drop_duplicates(['testtime','responsetime'],keep='first')` check to see if testtime had the same value between the row index 1 and 2 & if responsetime had the same value between the row index 1 and 2? 

I want to only keep one of the values only when both column values are the same between multiple rows.

Comment: if you do drop duplicates with subset of ['testtime', 'responsetime'] then it will treat any row that has the same testtime and responsetime as a duplicate and it will be dropped. It will only keep the first instance of it.

This will also remove anything that has different student ids since you are only defining two columns as the subset to determine duplicates on. This might not be ideal for your case considering you want to do a group by based on the other columns

Comment: I did not work.. the shape of the df did not change.

Comment: what are you expecting the shape of the df to be? are there columns you are expecting to drop?

Comment: Shouldn't the rows with duplicate 'testtime' and 'responsetime' drop from the dataframe?